# Bash indirect variable reference in azure devops release pipeline

Tags: bash, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm building a release pipeline in Azure Devops. In one of the steps I'm using an inline bash script to retrieve the value of a secret previously retrieved by a KeyVault step.

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the comma-separated list of connected systems from the pipeline variable
connected_systems=$(echo "$(connectedSystems)")
echo "${connected_systems}"

# Loop through each connected system
IFS=',' read -r -a connected_systems_array <<< "$connected_systems"
for connected_system_name in "${connected_systems_array[@]}"; do
    
# Get the password value from the corresponding pipeline variable
    password="${!connected_system_name}"
    echo "connected_system_name: ${connected_system_name}"
    echo "password: ${password}"

    # Replace placeholder with password in the file
    sed -i "s/\.password=placeholder/\.password=$password/g" $(propertiesFile)
done

echo "$(propertiesFile)"
cat $(propertiesFile)
```

My problem is that I can't find the way to actually retrieve the value from the pipeline variable with the name of ${connectedSystem}.

I've tried:

```
password=$(${connected_system_name}) -> Doesn't work
password=$(eval echo "${connected_system_name}") -> Doesn't work
password=$(eval "${connected_system_name}") -> Doesn't work
```

I'm running out of ideas as I thoght I would just need to pass the string value to the $() function to retrieve the value of the pipeline variable...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a few cases where you do `echo $(var)` instead of `echo ${var}` (parentheses vs curly braces), is that intentional? If `connectedSystems` is a variable and not a command then you want braces.

Comment: Other than that nothing looks obviously wrong, if that doesn't fix the issue then try inspecting the value of `connected_system_name` and maybe use `env` to check if that name exists in the program environment.

Comment: `foo=$(echo $(bar))` is basically a long way to write `foo=$(bar)`. Capturing a command's standard output only to write it back to standard output is generally unnecessary.

Comment: I've never used Azure, but the idea of writing things retrieved from KeyVault to disk seems suspect. The main point of such services is to avoid committing secrets to (unencrypted) files in the first place.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: @tjm3772 this is because in DevOps Tasks $(variable) is a global pipeline variable and ${variable} is a local one in the script.

Comment: @chepner yes , I’m just printing it out to test but the idea is to have it masked later during runtime and delete artifacts after the whole operation.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that I can't find the way to actually retrieve the value from the pipeline variable with the name of ${connectedSystem}.

In order to retrieve values from the Azure Devops release pipeline variables you need to use the syntax here- **`$(variablename)`**

***I have updated your code to get the value of connectedSystem like and its system's password like below:-***

**Bash script:-**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Get the comma-separated list of connected systems from the pipeline variable
connected_systems=$(connectedSystems)

echo $(connectedSystems)

# Get the password values directly from the pipeline variables
system1=$(system1)
system2=$(system2)
system3=$(system3)

# Loop through each system and print its value
for connected_system_name in system1 system2 system3; do
    # Get the password value for the current system
    password=$(eval echo "\$$connected_system_name")
    
    # Print system name and password
    echo "connected_system_name: $connected_system_name"
    echo "password: $password"
done
```

**My  Release pipeline variables:-**

[image]

***Output:-***

[image]

Reference:-
[Define variables - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&source=recommendations&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch)

Complete bash script:-

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Get the comma-separated list of connected systems from the pipeline variable
connected_systems=$(connectedSystems)
echo "connectedSystems: $connected_systems"

# Get the password values directly from the pipeline variables
system1=$(system1)
system2=$(system2)
system3=$(system3)

# Loop through each system and print its value
for connected_system_name in system1 system2 system3; do
    # Get the password value for the current system
    password=$(eval echo "\$$connected_system_name")
    
    # Print system name and password
    echo "connected_system_name: $connected_system_name"
    echo "password: $password"
done

# Assuming propertiesFile contains the path to file.properties
propertiesFile="$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/file.properties"

# Assuming you want to extract the value associated with a key named "example_key"
example_value=$(grep '^example_key=' "$propertiesFile" | cut -d '=' -f 2)

echo "Value associated with example_key: $example_value"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the '**`connectedSystems`**' is a secret in Azure key vault, the [Azure Key Vault task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-key-vault-v2?view=azure-pipelines) will download the secret value as string and set it as a secret variable in the pipeline. The pipeline secret variable has the same (**`connectedSystems`**) with the Azure key vault secret. The values of secret variables will be always masked as "**`***`**" in the console logs for security in pipelines. See "[**Set secret variables**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables)".

After the Azure Key Vault task, on the subsequent steps within the same job, you normally can directly reference the secret variables using the expression "**`$(varName)`**".

However, on the script tasks (such as [Bash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/bash-v3?view=azure-pipelines), [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-v2?view=azure-pipelines), [CmdLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/cmd-line-v2?view=azure-pipelines), etc..), it is recommended to map the secret variables into environment variables and reference the environment variables in the scripts. For example.

```yaml
- task: Bash@3
  env:
    MY_SECRET_TOKEN: $(mySecretToken)
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: echo $MY_SECRET_TOKEN | az devops login --org https://dev.azure.com/myorg
```

---